# Javascript window/image onload timing - this shouldn't work, but it does

Tags: javascript

This is a simple program to load two images, place the second one on top of the first one, and then fade the top one in or out using setInterval and opacity changes.  It works perfectly, although looking at the code, it should fail if botPic is loaded before topPic (a race condition).  But it doesn't, and I can't figure out why it doesn't.

```
  window.onload = function() {
    var topPic = document.getElementById("topPic");
    var botPic = document.getElementById("botPic");
  }

  function findPosition(obj) {
    var curleft = 0;
    var curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
      do {
        curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
        curtop += obj.offsetTop;
      } while ((obj = obj.offsetParent) !== null);
    }
    return [curleft, curtop];
  }

  function doTopPicLoad() {
    topPicLoaded = 1;
    if (botPicLoaded == 1) {
      startFader();
    }
  }

  function doBotPicLoad() {
    var leftTop = findPosition(botPic);
    topPic.style.left = leftTop[0];
    topPic.style.top  = leftTop[1];
    botPicLoaded = 1;

    if (topPicLoaded == 1) {
      startFader();
    }
  }

  function startFader() {
    // do stuff
  }

  <img id="botPic" onload='doBotPicLoad()' src="DMH_0991-M-72-720x576.jpg">
  <img id="topPic" onload='doTopPicLoad()' src="DMH_0991-72-720x576.jpg">
```

Logging, either through console.log or by insertion into the DOM, always shows "window.load" as the last item executed.  doTopPicLoad and doBotPicLoad appear in various orders, but they ALWAYS show topPic and botPic as valid objects.

```
topPic.onload [object HTMLImageElement] [object HTMLImageElement]
botPic.onload [object HTMLImageElement] [object HTMLImageElement]
startFader
window.onload
```

However, if I start out like this, it usually (always?) fails.

```
var topPic;
var botPic;

window.onload = function() {
  topPic = document.getElementById("topPic");
  botPic = document.getElementById("botPic");
}
```

My only thought:

The Javascript interpreter "knows" that it has to delay execution of any statement which references any vars declared inside the window.onload function - until that function completes.  (This seems pretty far-fetched, but it would explain it).

I don't want to leave a race-condition in my code, but there doesn't seem to be any actual "race" occurring.  Can anyone explain why this code always works?

Actual example:
http://www.davehennessey.com/photography/small-buildings/DMH_0991X2.html

Thanks - Dave

Comment: The JavaScript interpreter is definitely not doing what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your window "load" handler is setting up two **local** variables. Your script is referring directly to the "topPic" and "botPic" `<img>` DOM elements. If the two lines didn't start with `var`, things wouldn't really change, because "topPic" and "botPic" are *already* referring to the values that'll be returned by those calls to `.getElementById()`.

That is, when your code (outside the window "load" handler) refers to the variables "topPic" and "botPic", what it's accessing are the DOM elements bound to the window object via those names. The browser does that because the elements have those "id" values.

Because the functions don't get called until the `<img>` element "load" events fire, things work. (Setting the "style" of the `<img>` elements will work fine before the images load.) Your window "load" handler is superfluous and has no effect on the system at all.

Comment: You are correct.  I took out the window.onload and it still works fine. Amazingly, I didn't know that the browser automatically created a variable for each ID - I always did an explicit getElById.  You never stop learning.  This also explains an old IE6 quirk - var thisName=document.getElemendById("thisName") would throw an error.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As Pointy points out, your topPic and botPic variables are local only to the anonymous onload function and will not affect the rest of the page.

Have you considered defining a Pic class?

```
function Pic(elem) {
  this.elem = elem;
  this.loaded = false
}

// define global objects topPic and botPic that have elem and loaded attributes

window.onload = function() {
    topPic = new Pic(document.getElementById("topPic"));
    botPic = new Pic(document.getElementById("botPic"));
  }

  function findPosition(obj) {
    var curleft = 0;
    var curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
      do {
        curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
        curtop += obj.offsetTop;
      } while ((obj = obj.offsetParent) !== null);
    }
    return [curleft, curtop];
  }

  function doTopPicLoad() {
    topPic.loaded = true;
    if ( botPic.loaded ) {
      startFader();
    }
  }

  function doBotPicLoad() {
    var leftTop = findPosition(botPic.elem);
    topPic.elem.style.left = leftTop[0];
    topPic.elem.style.top  = leftTop[1];
    botPic.loaded = true;

    if ( topPic.loaded ) {
      startFader();
    }
  }

  function startFader() {
    // do stuff
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, but I only have two pics.  I'm old fashioned (learned Basic on a GE 265, Fortran on an IBM 7090) and never really got comfortable with the OOP stuff.  I have to relearn it every time I use it.